# Django: how to store information of multiple logins of the same user from different devices

Tags: django

In Django User model, we store the last_login to know when is the users last login.

But assuming i am logging from firefox and chrome browsers and I want to store the information of the device and its login time, how can we do that.

Later i can see from where all the devices the user is currently logged in and what times is logged in from those devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider creation of a new model with relation many to one to application User.
This model named say `UserSession` could store information such as device type, login time etc. and could be easily queried for given user.

```
import datetime

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class UserSession(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    device_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    login_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Instance of this model could be created on each new login time.

Comment: I was also thinking of creating another table. But i thought may be django is storing it somewhere

Comment: You could also create custom session model and store these values there https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/#example but querying this table for given user would be probably more complicated.